# Create server-side for Stripe service on Android

Tags: android, token, stripe-payments, server-side

I want to integrate Stripe's mobile payments services inside my Android app, but when I read the [Android Integration Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) in Stripe's website, I noticed to this code:

```
...
new TokenCallback() {
    public void onSuccess(Token token) {
      // Send token to your server
    }
    ...
}
```

I didn't understand what they mean by "Send token to your server"... What Server do they mean? My own server (like AWS EC2)? Or a private server running on their servers?

Anyway, I clicked on [Charge your user immediately](https://stripe.com/docs/charges) at the end of the page and I saw a code for a server-side, but again, I didn't realize what do they mean by "server-side"??

Could you please help me? I want to get over with it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical payment flow with Stripe can be divided in two steps:

1. Client-side, you collect the customer's payment information and turn it into a token. In a web app, this is done via [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js). In a mobile app, this is done with Stripe's [iOS](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) or [Android](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) SDK.

   Once the token has been created, you then send it to your backend server.
2. Server-side, you use the token to [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge), or to [create a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) which will save the payment information so you can create more charges in the future without having to collect the payment information again.

   [This tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/charges) explains the server-side part of the flow.

The main advantage of this two-steps flow is that your server never deals with PCI-sensitive card information. It only deals with tokens which represent cards but hides the PCI-sensitive information. This greatly eases the burden of [PCI compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security#pci-dss-guidelines).

Comment: But how can I create the server? Will AWS EC2 will be good for this server?

Comment: Any server that's capable of running a web server and backend code in your programming language of choice (PHP, Ruby, Python...) will do.

Comment: I don't know a lot of how to use servers in android so could you please send me an example of how to pass the token to a server?